# Bootstrap Validation Not Working when using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

My Bootstrap validation works fine in form-control, see below image

[image]

My Code is:

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator" id="myform">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Select Teacher" id="ddlMultiTeacher" style="background-color: white" required>
                                <%--<option value="">None</option>--%>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Select Subject" id="ddlMultiSubject" style="background-color: white" required>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Select Class" id="ddlMultiClass" style="background-color: white" required>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Select Section" id="ddlMultiSection" style="background-color: white" required>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <%--                    <button  id="btnSubmit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>--%>
                        <input id="btnGenerateSchedule" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

but whenever I use my buttonsubmit code via jquery, my validation stops working.

```
$('#btnGenerateSchedule').click(function (e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm("<b>Are you sure?</b>", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            GenerateSchedule();
            //bootbox.alert({
            //    title: "Alert",
            //    message: "Your Schedule Has Been Generated !"
            //})
        } else {
            //console.log("User declined dialog");
        }
    });
})
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? am I missing some plugins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write jquery submit or click event, then bootstrap or html validation does not work. If you want html/bootstrap validation should work before jquery click/submit event then do as follows:

```
$('#btnGenerateSchedule').click(function (e) {
if($("form")[0].checkValidity()){
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm("<b>Are you sure?</b>", function (result) {
       if (result) {
           GenerateSchedule();
       } else {
        //console.log("User declined dialog");
       }
    });
}       });
```

$("form")[0]) depends on form in page. If it is first form in your page, then form[0], if it is second form in your page, then $("form")[1](https://blog.webnersolutions.com/jquery-and-html5-validations-together)) and so on.

For detail, you can visit link: [html and jquery validation together](https://blog.webnersolutions.com/jquery-and-html5-validations-together)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('form').on('click','#btnGenerateSchedule',function (e) {
debugger;
e.preventDefault();

bootbox.confirm("<b>Are you sure?</b>", function (result) {
    if (result) {
        GenerateSchedule();
        //bootbox.alert({
        //    title: "Alert",
        //    message: "Your Schedule Has Been Generated !"
        //})
    } else {
        //console.log("User declined dialog");
    }
});
})
```